# Shell Scripting for Testing

Tags: testing, shell

I'm trying to master shell scripting for testing APIs & Automation testing.

Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Links to web sites, pdf's etc would be appreciated.

Comment: Which API are you attempting to automate the testing of? Language, platform etc?

Comment: I was in general asking about API's written in languages like C, C++ and Python. How do you mock the API functionality ?

Comment: I've updated my answer regarding your comment on mocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For web testing I have used [Watir](http://watir.com/) & for API testing xUnit (where x can be 'j', 'n' etc)

If you tell us which platform your are programming/testing then more specific answers should be forthcoming.

**Edit:**
For mocking C++ there is [googlemock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) library. It's easy to find others, search the web for "mock [language]" where [language] is C++, C, Python.

Comment: I just confined myself to API and Automation testing, i Have edited my question.

Comment: @coolrockers2007: sorry, was editing your question when you changed it; have tried to correct.